# Add an OCR layer over MS Word images (extracted from PDF)

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion, ocr

I'm working on a PDF (that i created with LaTeX) and I need to convert in into a MS Word document, but keeping the *exactly* original typesetting and design.
Since all the converters from PDF to Word will break some stuff, I thought that it would be a good idea to

- use the PDF as background in the Word file
- add an OCR layer to select the text (I do not need to edit the text; just looking at it and adding some comments).

Is there any way to achieve that? Including PDF's images into Word is easy, but I don't know how to add an OCR layer over it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Such a layer doesn't exist.

I can think of two methods:

1. If you still have your original LaTeX document,
   converting it to Word is easier and more precise.
   One tool you can use is [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/), where the conversion is done
   with the command:

   ```
    pandoc mydoc.tex -o mydoc.docx
   ```

   For more information see the article
   [How to Convert from Latex to MS Word with ‘Pandoc’](https://medium.com/@zhelinchen91/how-to-convert-from-latex-to-ms-word-with-pandoc-f2045a762293)
2. Use the best converter you find to convert from PDF to Word and correct it
   by hand.

Comment: Thanks! I have already tried with pandoc, but the result is terrible. Your second method is the most logic one, but I was hoping that I could use some other solution, that does not forces me to correct and edit each PDF I convert (there are also losses of typesetting quality)